# Javascript Counter function that counts number of words in the text

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to write a javascript counter function that takes a text argument that counts the number of words in the text.

The return output also has to be displayed as a single object.

Comment: What is a word? `str.match(/\w+/g).length;`

Comment: *The return output also has to be displayed as a single object.* You can display it however you want--as an alert, in the console, or by sticking it in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

try to use  `text.split(' ').length`

```
var countOf = function(text){
 return text.split(' ').length
}
```

Comment: what about tabs and returns

Comment: Oh, my bad. May be instead regexp helps. E.g. `text.(/\s+/).length`

Comment: @RudolfManusadzhyan How many words is `" Oh my! ! ! ! "` ?

Comment: yes, that what makes programing cool :)

Answer (score 0):

the way to do is to count every is_space() in the string that is not preceded by an other is_space(), add to the result the last word if it remain.

Comment: think about the min length of the word, can punctuations be counted as words?